# Running gitlab and gitlab-shell separately

Tags: docker, gitlab

I'm building docker images for gitlab and I want to follow docker design – one process in one container. Is it possible to run gitlab shell in a separate container (with sshd)? Should I be aware of any pitfalls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it's not possible, according to [these lines](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/config/gitlab.yml.example#L499) in `gitlab.yml`:

```
  ## GitLab Shell settings
  gitlab_shell:
    path: /home/git/gitlab-shell/
    hooks_path: /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
```